# php url data fetch stop on particular time

Tags: php

I am using php 5.2 and I am fetching data from url using file_get_contents function. This is loop for 5000 and I have divided into 500 slots and set a script like this.
For 500 it is taking 3 hours to complete because for some url it is taking too much time and for some it is in 1 sec that is fine.

What I want if url is taking more than 30 sec then skip and go for next.
I want to stop fetch after 30 sec.

```
    <?php
// Create the stream context
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'timeout' => 1       // Timeout in seconds
    )
));

// Fetch the URL's contents
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."\n";
$contents = file_get_contents('http://example.com', 0, $context);
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."\n";
// Check for empties
if (!empty($contents))
{
    // Woohoo
//    echo $contents;
echo "file fetched";
}
else
{
echo $contents;
echo "more than 30 sec"; 
}
?>
```

I have already done that it is not working for me because file_get_contents function is not stoping it will continue , then only thing now I am getting no result after 30 sec but time it is taking sameas u can see in output.
Output of php

2012-03-09 11:26:38
2012-03-09 11:26:40
more than 30 sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the HTTP timeout. (Not tested)

```
<?php
$ctx = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'timeout' => 30
     )
));
file_get_contents("http://example.com/", 0, $ctx);
```

[Source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php#82527)

**Edit:** I don't know why it isn't working with this code by you. But if you don't manage it to bring it to work with this you may also want to give [CURL](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) a try. This could be eventually also faster for that (but I don't know if that is really faster...).
If that would work for you, you could than use the [curl_setopt function](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) to set the timeout time with the `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` flag.

Comment: I have done this but no solution because file_get_content wont stop the process only thing i will not get any result after time which i have defined check in my question update

Answer (score 0):

There some info on the php manual about timeouts.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

there is mention of the following as of php 5.2.1

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 120);   
$a = file_get_contents("http://abcxyz.com");
```

or adding a context which is more or less the same.

```
// Create the stream context
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'timeout' => 3      // Timeout in seconds
    )
));
// Fetch the URL's contents
$contents = file_get_contents('http://abcxyz.com', 0, $context);`
```

A third option is using PHP's fsockopen which has an explicit timeout option
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php

```
$timeout = 2; // seconds
$fp = fsockopen($url, 80, $errNo, $errString, $timeout); 
/* stops connecting after 2 seconds, 
  stores the error Number in $errNo, 
  the error String in $errStr */
```

To save writing a lot of code, you could use it as a quick check if host is up.

ie:

```
if (pingLink($domain,$timeout)) {
  file_get_contents()
} 

function pingLink($domain,$timeout=30){ 
    $status    = 0; //default site is down
    $file      = fsockopen($domain,"r");
    if ($file) {
       $status = 1;  // Site is up
       fclose($file);
    }
    return $status;
}
```

Comment: I have done this but no solution because file_get_content wont stop the process only thing i will not get any result after time which i have defined check in my question update

Comment: thanks for your update, had you also tried the alternative method in my post?

Comment: no that i can't do that..becoz this change will effect everywhere .I want this change for this php only that y i am focusing on file_get_contents

Comment: but in my code how should i use this ....becoz file_get_content function i want to stop after time which specified

Comment: I've modified my answer with a summarised example.

Comment: i used this code as every time it is giving me 0 as status ....for fsockopen anything i need to check please let me know